# updating ios app without appstore submission

Tags: iphone, ios

Can we use archived custom build file archive of class object and then read this class for the updates in iOS 
eg:

```
 interface base  {
 -(void) methodbase1;
-(void) methodbase2;

}
base *objbase =[[base alloc]init];

 archiving objbase -->to file 
 {
 //if we provide this file from remote server can we update
 }
reading objbase <--from file
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cocoa supports a number of ways of [dynamically loading code](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingCode/LoadingCode.html).  But these are all forbidden on iOS, and you won't get past App Store review if you try to load code using any of these methods.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just deserializing data members and not trying anything fancy with loading dynamic code, this is perfectly OK.

Comment: I need some fancy too .. I like to update some function in it .:)